# 2012 VW Jetta Intermittent Start

Tags: starting, jetta, cranks-wont-run, intermittent-problems

My wife and I have a 2012 VW Jetta w/ 100K miles on it. We have an issue where the car will not start when we drive it and then let it sit for an hour or two, but will start fine after sitting for several hours. The engine turns over when we try to start it, but doesn't run. The mechanic has tried a few things, including replacing the camshaft sensor, but without success.

Any ideas? What type of issues could occur only shortly after the car has been driven? Something to do with the temperature of the car? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is the check engine light on (or does it come on)?

Comment: The check engine light, battery light, and Electronic Power Control (EPC) light come on. We have replaced the battery, which did not fix the problem.

Comment: Have you checked for what codes might be present? Have them read?

Comment: The mechanic has had trouble having the issue repeat itself, but I understand that they've ran the codes and haven't found anything

Comment: I have edited the body of your question for clarity, hoping to make it clearer for the reader. If you disagree with my changes, you can revert the wording back to your original text.